# Sprite Sheet for Musical Notes?

Tags: music, spritesheet, spritebatch

Does anybody know of a sprite sheet of musical notes (half note, minim)? I am trying to draw musical notes onto an android canvas.

Comment: are you sure this is a right place to ask this question?

Comment: No research effort shown and this doesn't really seem to be on topic for this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to locate art resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two fonts out there called Anastasia and Maestro. They consist of musical notes.
If their license and your software license are compatible, you could just embed them in your application and render the notes using that.

Comment: This is the current path I am going, but my target platform will not have font support. I am considering rendering my own sprite sheet, but this seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Any sprite sheet you get from another source will have some form of licensing to deal with (even if it's "you're free to use this for whatever").  I'd recommend just rolling your own, that way you can make sure the graphical look suits the rest of your program and nobody can say you "stole" your assets from somewhere else.

Comment: Well, you can simply download the font, install on your PC and then open mspaint(or any other graphics tool like gimp or PS), write every possible font glyph then just save that image. If I'm not mistaken, this is called `rasterizing`, and even more, if the font have a license that you cant afford on your game, this license is only valid for the font generation instructions, that is the TTF font file. If you just use the generated image by the font, you won't be breaking nothing. Although I'm not a lawyer, this is what people tell me.